# How to access HttpSession from odata4j ProducerFactory?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, odata, odata4j

For populating entries only visible to the user I need to know which user is logged in. This information is stored in my HttpSession object. How can I access this object from an odata4j ProducerFactory implementation?